# jQuery, fullCalendar & PHP loop -- trailing comma breaking event render on IE8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops, fullcalendar

I use this PHP/CodeIgniter code to generate events on fullCalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        events: [
                <?php foreach($cal_data as $row): ?>
                    {   
                  title : '<?php echo $row->pt_name . ' ' . $row->value_2; ?>',
                  start : '<?php echo $row->date . 'T' . $row->time .'Z'; ?>',
                  url   : '<?php echo base_url() . 'events/events_edit/' . $row->record_id; ?>',
                  color: '<?php echo $row->value_4; ?>'
                    }, //  <=== this comma is the problem
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                ],
etc...
```

As you can see on line 10 there is that final comma which will close the event data, and the loop goes on. A typical output will be:

```
events: [
        {   
              title : 'Test1',
          start : '2011-04-07T08:45:00Z',
          url   : http://example.com/events/events_edit/81',
          color: '#ed9d2b'
                        },
        {   
          title : 'Test2',
          start : '2011-04-09T08:45:00Z',
          url   : http://example.com/events/events_edit/82',
          color: '#ed9d2b'
                        }, // <======= trailing comma
```

Unfortunately the trailing comma from the last event breaks the render on IE8 (events show nicely on Cr, FF, Saf).

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: This is what you get with spaghetti code, put your loop output in a string a then run `trim($string, ",")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're building JSON.  Why not actually, say, build JSON?  Alter your code to build a multi-dimensional array instead of output.  You'd want a structure like

```
$stuff = array(
    'events' => array(
        0 => array(
            'title' => ...,
            'start' => ...
            'url' => ...
            'color' => ...
        ),
        // etc
    ),
    // etc
));
```

By building the data separately from emitting it, you can ensure you have it correct to begin with, and let the JSON encoder worry about the syntax:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(<?php echo json_encode($stuff); ?>);
```

Comment: thanks @charles -- one issue though -- when I follow your suggestion the final output has the typical JSON format `events: {"86":{"title":"Test 1","start":"2011-04-20T09:15:00Z","allday":"false","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/events\/events_edit\/86","color":"#FF9CB3"}` -- and this format won't be understood by fullCalendar -- how do I get this formatted like my code on OP?

Comment: @torr, the events array has to be zero-indexed.  If it's not zero-indexed, it'll end up as a Javascript object instead of as a Javascript array, which is the source of your problem.

Comment: got it -- removed the key now works perfect --thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: The quotes need to be there, as that is how JSON works.  You *can* exclude them, but there is never a problem with them being present.  If the events aren't showing, perhaps there is another problem.  It might be that it doesn't understand the date format.  [Compare your date format to the date format in the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/).